# Jamming with USB SDR

Tags: software-defined-radio, noise, transmitter

Could an attacker use a simple USB SDR dongle, as long as it is capable of transmitting within a certain range, to jam frequencies?

I saw Lady Ada build the WaveBubble which is basically a dual-band, tunable RF jammer. The difficulty of construction was very high though. I'm aware this is against FCC regulations. It's a hypothetical question.

Comment: The FCC doesn't play when it comes to this sort of thing. I wouldn't even go down this road.

Comment: I said hypothetical in the question. Its risk assessment.

Comment: Yes. Yup. Affirmative.

Answer (score 1):

As I have said in my first post if someone / something is jamming radio services they may "enlist" help of hams using RDF to locate and eliminate the source. The FCC does not play around when important services are being jammed.

The answer to your question: Yes, as long as the device being used as a jammer has enough power to transmit over the target it will be effectively jammed.

Comment: The hackrf one has a welldocumented interface, and high bandwidth. It outputs a fairly weak signal, but if it is amplified it could do it. Please don't cry 'FCC!' just because someone is being curious -  weren't you all curious toddlers once?

Comment: And woe+wrath ensues if someone jams a ham, break out the triangulation kit, but OP was just asking a very innocent question. The yardstick one can do <=1GHz tx, albeit not as recklessly awesome as the hackrf. What about a high powered spark transmitter at 10000RPM?